# Найти путь к файлу в java. Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, path

Нужно программно в runtime запустить script.sql, который находиться в папке webapp. Подскажите, как это сделать? Приложение работает на сервлетах.

Comment: Что за папка webapp? А прожекте интелижи-идееи? В war-архиве? На диске сервера?

Comment: да, прожекчу на идее, сервер tomcat. в итоге должен получить war-file.

Comment: в нем находится описание БД? или что?

Comment: @ Mikhail Vaysman спасибо, снизу мне дали ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно знать путь файла внутри war-архива

```
String path = "/script.sql";
// String path = "/WEB-INF/script.sql";
```

Заодно сразу получим `ServletContext`, потому что все полезные методы в этом классе

```
ServletContext sc = request.getServletContext();
```

Тогда узнать путь можно так

```
String rp = sc.getRealPath(path);
```

Если хотите открыть этот файл, то не надо искать его реальный путь (да и не всегда это возможно на самом деле). А надо сразу открывать так

```
InputStream is = sc.getResourceAsStream(path);
```

Можно получить URL файла (если вдруг понадобится передать в какой-нибудь метод, принимающий URL)

```
URL url = sc.getResource(path);
```

Comment: спасибо, поянтно ответили. скажите, пожалуйста. Я так понимаю, что путь `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` возвращает корень проекта с которого запускается. Я так задавал доступ к css `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`/file.css. Но когда  я деплою свое приложение на TOMCAT через менеджер приложений - у меня получается приложение 2-го уровня **http://localhost:8080/app/** и эти путя уже не видит т.к. СSS уже неходится не вкорне, а в "/app/file.css". Возможно ли как то по другому указыать путь, чтобы сервер его видел корректно в обоих случаях?

Comment: `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` или короче `${request.contextPath}` это и есть `/app`. `/app`  и есть корень. `${request.contextPath}/file.css` будет соответственно `/app/file.css`. Всё правильно. Это единственный верный способ. Должно работать. Дело в чём-то другом или путаете с каким-то другим корнем. Убедитесь что file.css находится в корне war-архива. Почистите кеш браузера.

Comment: я, наверное, некорректно высказался. у меня само приложение запускается не по **localhost:8080/**, а по **localhost:8080/app**.  За счет этого, как я понял, и получается ошибка, т.к. `${request.contextPath}` ищет файл не в **localhost:8080/app** а в **localhost:8080/**. т.е. когда я его запусаю с идеи на томкэте- все работает хорошо (т.к. приложение в корне), а вот когда в непосредственно в томкэте - файлы по заданным путям не видит.

Comment: `${request.contextPath}` - фактический корень приложения, так называемый `context root`. В идее будет `/` в tomcat-е `/app` (по имени вашего war-архива). С этим всё верно. Можете убедиться,  выведя путь на страницу. Прямо в jsp поместите куда-нибудь  `<div>${request.contextPath}</div>` и увидите в браузере путь. Да и сами посудите, на фига была бы нужна переменная, которая всегда равна `/`?

Comment: Если в идее `${request.contextPath}/file.css` работает, а в томкате нет, то либо в war-архиве вообще нет `/file.css`, либо одно из двух. Проверьте содержимое `app.war`. Это обыкновенный архив zip, открывается и 7zip-ом и винрарным winrar-ом.

Comment: Поправочка. Если приложение запускается из корня сервера `localhost:8080/`, то `${request.contextPath}` будет пустой строкой, а не `/`. Может правильное `${request.contextPath}/file.css` написано слитно без `/`: `${request.contextPath}file.css`? Тогда в идее будет `file.css`, что может быть ещё правильным в некоторых случаях, а в томкат получается `/appfile.css`, что совершенно не верно.

Comment: я вручную почистил папку webapps в tomcat - все заработало. Вы пролили свет на этот вопрос, спасибо.